# How to do I call this function in Python?

Tags: python, function, file

I'm very new to Python and I can't seem to get functions down. I understand what they do and how to write them, but I don't know how to call them, especially when it comes to parameters.

```
import csv

def get_data_list(file):
    data_file = open("table.csv", "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
    return data_list
```

Comment: *"I understand ... how to write them"*: could you fix the indenting? NB: this function never uses the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you are trying to do inside your function. But you can call like this

```
import csv

def get_data_list(file):
    data_file = open("table.csv", "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
        return data_list

get_data_list("abc.csv")
```

Comment: I'm trying to take data from a csv file and put it in a new list after I've stripped, split it and added it to the list. I just want it to return the new data_list.

Comment: @TaylorPatterson I think what fallandlearn means is that you are passing a variable named file, then never using it as you have a hardcoded filename in your open statement. in this example `"abc.csv"` must be provided, as your function is expecting one input value, but it is then promptly thrown away.

Comment: @TaylorPatterson if you want to use the `data_list` that is returned by the function, simply assign a new variable to the called function: `data = get_data_list("abc.csv")`

Comment: also, you import the `csv` library, then never use any of it's functions.

Comment: At first, I had data_file as the parameter, but it kept saying it was undefined once I tried to call it as get_data_list(data_file)

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

data_list = list(csv.reader(open('table.csv', 'r')))
```

Comment: well, I have hard time interpreting the question. It says he doesn't know how to call functions and then calls open(), append(), strip() and split(). So, I just fixed the code

Comment: I think it's just the misunderstanding that user defined functions are any different (in how you call them) from built-in functions. We were all new once...

Answer (score 1):

Ok...
**First:** You forgot the identation in the lines above the function.
**Second:** I think you could decrease the indentation one level in the last line.
**Third:** You can call functions this way: *name_of_function(argument1, argument2, & so on...)*

Your code would look like this:

```
import csv

def get_data_list(file):
    data_file = open("table.csv", "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
    return data_list

get_data_list('file.csv')
```